# Hadoop NoSuchMethodError apache.commons.cli

Tags: java, hadoop, nosuchmethoderror, apache-commons-cli

I'm using `hadoop-2.7.2` and I did a MapReduceJob with IntelliJ. In my job, I'm using `apache.commons.cli-1.3.1` and I put the lib in the jar.

When I use the MapReduceJob on my Hadoop cluster I have a `NoSuchMethodError`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.commons.cli.Option.builder(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/commons/cli/Option$Builder;

I don't understand because the method exist in the class `Option` and the class `Option` is extracted from the `commons-cli.jar` to my application jar. Moreover, I don't have this issue with my others libraries.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I just found that hadoop use commons-CLi 1.2. I think this is the source of my issue but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You can try to exclude `commons-cli-1.2` from Hadoop dependency in your `pom.xml`, then Hadoop willl use your `commons-cli-1.3.1`. If it causes any errors, you'd better use `1.2` in your code.

Comment: I did something like that but my boss doesn't want this way because it doesn't fix the issue. If we have the same issue later with another lib, he doesn't want to fix the issue again. 

But thank you for your advice.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the sequence in which the jars are declared in the classpath. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 5):

We were able to fix this error using [maven class relocations](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html). If you are using the shade plugin to build your jar add following to pom.xml under appropriate section:

```
<!-- necessary to fix NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.Option.builder -->
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.apache.commons.cli</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>org.shaded.commons.cli</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
```

Also an explicit reference to v1.3+ of commons-cli needs to be added at the TOP of the dependencies section before any dependency that may have a transitive reference to an older version of commons-cli.

Comment: this solution worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be related to how the `classloader` is loading the classes. Because the `static Builder class` was in `common-cli 1.4`, while some of the `hadoop` dependencies were still referring to older version - the issue occurred.

In my case, the issue resolved by changing the sequence of jar file addition into the classpath in the shell script responsible for setting up environment before program execution. Earlier, I was adding the jar into classpath like

```
CLASSPATH=<Hadoop Jars>:<Common CLI jar>:$CLASSPATH
```

is changed to

```
CLASSPATH=<Common CLI jar>:<Hadoop Jars>:$CLASSPATH
```

and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this issue with the next gradle configuration:

```
 compile('org.apache.parquet:parquet-tools:1.9.0'){
  exclude module:"commons-cli"
 }
```