# NoSuchMethodError when trying to run Gobblin on Dataproc

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, google-cloud-dataproc, gobblin

I'm trying to run [Gobblin](https://github.com/linkedin/gobblin) on Google Dataproc but I'm getting this NoSuchMethodError and can't figure out how to solve.

```
Waiting for job output...
...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.Option.builder()Lorg/apache/commons/cli/Option$Builder;
        at gobblin.runtime.cli.CliOption
        ...
```

This same job (contents below) runs nice on my local hadoop setup (on my laptop) but does not on dataproc. Have someone ever attempted running Gobblin on Dataproc?

Here's my gobblin job file:

```
job.name=kafka2gcs
job.group=gkafka2gcs
job.description=Gobblin job to read messages from Kafka and save as is on GCS
job.lock.enabled=false

kafka.brokers=mykafka:9092
topic.whitelist=mytopic
bootstrap.with.offset=earliest

source.class=gobblin.source.extractor.extract.kafka.KafkaDeserializerSource
kafka.deserializer.type=BYTE_ARRAY
extract.namespace=nskafka2gcs

writer.builder.class=gobblin.writer.SimpleDataWriterBuilder
writer.destination.type=HDFS
mr.job.max.mappers=2
writer.output.format=txt
data.publisher.type=gobblin.publisher.BaseDataPublisher
metrics.enabled=false

fs.uri=file:///.
writer.fs.uri=${fs.uri}
mr.job.root.dir=gobblin
writer.output.dir=${mr.job.root.dir}/out
writer.staging.dir=${mr.job.root.dir}/stg

fs.gs.project.id=my-test-project
data.publisher.fs.uri=gs://my-bucket
state.store.fs.uri=${data.publisher.fs.uri}
data.publisher.final.dir=gobblin/pub
state.store.dir=gobblin/state
```

And these are the commands I issue for dataproc:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create myspark \
  --image-version 1.1 \
  --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
  --master-boot-disk-size 10 \
  --num-workers 2 \
  --worker-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
  --worker-boot-disk-size 10 
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop --cluster=myspark \
  --class gobblin.runtime.mapreduce.CliMRJobLauncher \
  --jars /opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-runtime-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-api-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-avro-json-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-codecs-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-core-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-core-base-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-crypto-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-crypto-provider-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-data-management-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-metastore-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-metrics-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-metrics-base-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-metadata-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gobblin-utility-0.10.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/avro-1.8.1.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/avro-mapred-1.8.1.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/config-1.2.1.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/data-2.6.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/gson-2.6.2.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/guava-15.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/guava-retrying-2.0.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/joda-time-2.9.3.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/kafka-clients-0.8.2.2.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/metrics-core-3.1.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/metrics-graphite-3.1.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/scala-library-2.11.8.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/influxdb-java-2.1.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/okhttp-2.4.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/okio-1.4.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/retrofit-1.9.0.jar,/opt/gobblin-dist/lib/reflections-0.9.10.jar \
  --properties mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true \
  -- -jobconfig gs://my-bucket/gobblin-kafka-gcs.job
```

I have already tried copying all gobblins lib jars inside `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib` on all machines of the dataproc cluster, but it didn't work either.

Any ideas?

```
gobblin 0.10.0
hadoop 2.7.3
dataproc image 1.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hadoop distribution is probably leaking its version of "commons-cli" into your classpath, and conflicting with the one Gobblin was compiled against. [Gobblin appears to depend on commons-cli 1.3.1](https://github.com/linkedin/gobblin/blob/df1b449062de6d7b9db2eecbea5d1effc3fe7f7b/gradle/scripts/dependencyDefinitions.gradle#L35) and [Hadoop 2.7.3 is on 1.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.3).

Typically if these dependencies come from your own application you'd use something like a [Maven shade plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43770406/3777211). If you're building Gobblin from source you could see if it compiles with commons-cli 1.2 or if it's actually a hard dependency.

If commons-cli 1.3.1 is fully backwards compatible, you could try deleting 
 `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar` on your cluster and adding your own downloaded `commons-cli-1.3.1.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was able to get past this error by removing commons-cli-1.2 and a few other jars from the path and replacing with gobblin specific ones. But I still am not able to successfully run it on dataproc :-(   I'm trying the [gobblin-users group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gobblin-users/YJv49jvJrtI/SoNFarAiBgAJ) now